# Node.js does not throw EADDRINUSE when port is used by Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I am writing an HTTP server in Node.js. I want to ensure that I get an error when the port I want to use is already allocated (which should be the `EADDRINUSE` error). So my code looks like this:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello world');
}).listen(3000, {
  console.log('Server running.');
}).on('error', err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Now when I run this server once, it works, and the server runs on port 3000. When I run the server a second time, it fails with an error, as expected.

So far, so good.

Now I start a Docker container that uses port 3000 (I am using Docker for macOS 17.12). When I now run my Node.js application, I get the message that the server is running, but it does not respond – so apparently it is not running?

If I change the line

```
}).listen(3000, {
```

to

```
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', {
```

then I actually get the error message. So, what is different in the case with Docker? Why can the server be started without an error, but why is it not reachable then? …?

PS: I originally thought that Docker may bind to IPv4, and Node.js to IPv6, but no matter whether I access http://localhost:3000, http://127.0.0.1:3000, or http://[::1]:3000 – it's always the Docker container that replies.

PPS: The specific Docker container is not important – I get the behavior with *any* Docker container that uses port 3000. If you want to reproduce it, you may use `docker run -d -p 3000:80 nginx`.

Comment: Since you are 47k+, I don't mean to offend you by telling you that you need to include [tag:docker] in your question, since it's obvious the issue comes from there.

Comment: You're perfectly right, I added the tag. Thanks for pointing this out – actually I just forgot it! Thanks :-)

Comment: @GoloRoden have you tried running your docker with `-p 3000:3000`?

Comment: No, as this shouldn't be relevant (the internal port of the Docker container *is* 8080, not 3000), but the host port is set to 3000 either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you running app in container, docker allocates separate virtual network interface for each container. You can actually see them inside your image (`docker run -it my_node_container /bin/bash`, `ifconfig`). So when you not specify 0.0.0.0, it binds to local interface, which in not exposed outside of container. If you do bind to 0.0.0.0 it is now exposed outside of container (or not, depending your network configuration, you have to map port or run `-net=host`). So now it can conflict with other apps listening on same port.

Comment: Yes, apparently it conflicts – and actually this is what I expect. BUT: Why does Node.js not complain about the port being used?

Comment: Because there are multiple network interface. And port is NOT actually used on the interface you bind to. This port is used on different interface. When you bind to 0.0.0.0 it binds to ALL interfaces, including one with with port 3000 already used. So it is not nodejs issue.

Comment: Ah okay, I see! Thanks :-)